# How to use Apple Push Notifications to update a Passbook

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, passbook

I have created Passbooks and they are loaded onto my customer's iOS devices. I need to update these Passbooks. According to the [Passbook docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Updating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH5-SW1) you need to use the Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) to trigger a pull from the iOS device in order to update the Passbook. This APNS push consists of a "push token" and a "pass type id." However, the APNS body is to be left empty.

The [APNS docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html) talk about a "device token" needed to send a push notification but make no mention of a "push token."

Is an APNS "device token" the same as a Passbook "push token"? How do I send the Passbook "pass type id" in my APNS push?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- The push token is given to your server when the device registers.

It is found in the body of the POST request in a JSON dictionary.
For example:

{
 "pushToken":"PushTokenFromDevice"
}

- The pass type id is embedded with the certificate used to generate the push notification to Apple's Push Notification Service

If you need a PHP implementation, I recommend: [APNS PHP](https://github.com/duccio/ApnsPHP)

Comment: Thanks! The cert signing part is what I missed. I have the right cert and everything looks good.